# How to Change Visual Studio Code Quick Fix Language?

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-code, editor, quickfix

I have a small problem with Visual Studio Code, I can't find place to change language of FIX tooltip(please check attached screen shot), I hate to use Polish lang in programs, a specialy when it's mixed with English UI. I can't find any solution online.

Configuration display language (after CTRL+Shift+P)  is set to

```
{
    // Defines VS Code's display language.
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=761051 for a list of supported languages.

    "locale":"en" // Changes will not take effect until VS Code has been restarted.
```

Any suggestions?

[image: Quick fix language screen]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Be sure to be very specific in your tagging, That helps people find questions to answer.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome, added visual-studio-code tag, cant find any more good ones thought.

Comment: I found workaround, however it is not perfect, changed the Windows 10 language to English, now Quick Fix text is in English.

Answer (score 8):

The Quick Fix strings are part of the C# extension and not VS Code itself.

Assuming you're using `ms-vscode.csharp`, the issue you've described seems stuck in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2513).

The workaround is to delete the OmniSharp localization files directory matching your Windows display language, in my case located here (your version will vary): `C:\Users\%username%\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.19.1\.omnisharp\1.32.19\pl`, after which the Quick Fix and debugging messages language will fall back to English.

Comment: in my case the path was: C:\Users\%username%\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.16\.omnisharp\1.37.16\fr

Answer (score 0):

Since I ran into the same problem with VS Code version 1.68.1, and the last answer by droopysinger is not applicable anymore, I dared to answer again.
I only used VS Code for C++ so the respective folder might change for your cases (see 'cpptools' in path).

However, navigate to folder

C:\Users\Username\ .vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.10.7-win32-x64\bin\messages

and delete all folders for the different languages. From the next start of VS Code, the language for Quick Fix messages should fall back to English again.

Note: in my case there was no folder for english messages. After deleting said folders, the folder ...\messages was empty.